# Table tab not working properly

Tags: html, tabs, html-table

I am trying to use table in my html code, and giving the tr tab, still the text is coming in a single row instead of multiple rows. Below is my code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<b> Question 1. </b> Match List-I with List-II and select the correct answer    using  the code given below the lists :
</tr>
<br>
<table class="tab_ques">
<tr><td>List-I (Town) </td><td>List-II( River Nearer to it)</td></tr>
<tr><td>A. Betul</td><td>1. Indravati</td></tr>
<tr><td>B. Jagdalpur</td><td>2.Narmada</td></tr>
<tr><td>C. Jabalpur</td><td>3.Shipra</td></tr>
<tr><td>D. Ujjain</td><td>4.Tapti</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<table class="tab_opt">
<tr><td>  </td><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
<tr><td> a. </td><td> 1 </td><td> 4 </td><td> 2 </td><td> 3 </td></tr>
<tr><td> b. </td><td> 4 </td><td> 1 </td><td> 2 </td><td> 3 </td></tr>
<tr><td> c. </td><td> 1 </td><td> 4 </td><td> 3 </td><td> 2 </td></tr>
<tr><td> d. </td><td> 4 </td><td> 1 </td><td> 3 </td><td> 2 </td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<tr>
<a href="ans_nobelprize_p1.html">Answer</a>
</tr>
<br>
<br>
<tr>
<td><b> Question 2. </b> Consider the following statement : </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
1.The nation-wide scheme of the National Child Labour Projects (NCLP) is run    Union Ministry of Social Justice amd Empowerment.<br>
2.Gurupadswamy Committee dealt with the issue of child labour.
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Which of the statements given above is/are correct?
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th> a. </th>
    <td> 1 only </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th> b. </th>
    <td> 2 only </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th> c. </th>
    <td> Both 1 and 2 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th> d. </th>
    <td> Neither 1 nor 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

```
.tab_ques
td {
margin-left:150px; 
width:300px ; border: 1px solid none; 
}

.tab_opt
tr, td{
margin-left:50px; 
width:30px ; border: 1px solid none; 
}
```

This is my complete code. hope this gives the clear picture of where I am going wrong.

Its fine upto q1. But as it reaches Question 2, its formatting is all gone.

Answer (score 1):

Add  `<td>` after `<tr>`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the td tags in your first row.  And the br tags will do nothing there.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b> Question 1. </b> Match List-I with List-II and select the correct answer using the code given below the lists :</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="tab_ques">
                <tr>
                    <td>List-I (Town) </td>
                    <td>List-II( River Nearer to it)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>A. Betul</td>
                    <td>1. Indravati</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>B. Jagdalpur</td>
                    <td>2.Narmada</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>C. Jabalpur</td>
                    <td>3.Shipra</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>D. Ujjain</td>
                    <td>4.Tapti</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="tab_opt">
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> a. </td>
                    <td> 1 </td>
                    <td> 4 </td>
                    <td> 2 </td>
                    <td> 3 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> b. </td>
                    <td> 4 </td>
                    <td> 1 </td>
                    <td> 2 </td>
                    <td> 3 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> c. </td>
                    <td> 1 </td>
                    <td> 4 </td>
                    <td> 3 </td>
                    <td> 2 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> d. </td>
                    <td> 4 </td>
                    <td> 1 </td>
                    <td> 3 </td>
                    <td> 2 </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="ans_nobelprize_p1.html">Answer</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b> Question 2. </b> Consider the following statement : </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1.The nation-wide scheme of the National Child Labour Projects (NCLP) is run Union Ministry of Social Justice amd Empowerment.<br>
            2.Gurupadswamy Committee dealt with the issue of child labour.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Which of the statements given above is/are correct?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th> a. </th>
                    <td> 1 only </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> b. </th>
                    <td> 2 only </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> c. </th>
                    <td> Both 1 and 2 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> d. </th>
                    <td> Neither 1 nor 2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That too did not work. It is coming like this: Which of the statements given above is/are correct? a. 1 only b. 2 only c. Both 1 and 2 d. Neither 1 nor 2 .                                                                                                                                   Where as I need the options to come in different rows. I tried running in chrome and IE. But it is same every where.

Comment: The options are now in different rows.  What do you really want?

Comment: Okay, above code modified.  See if that's what you want.

Comment: this is what I need, but, when I am using it with my main code, its failing...I am unable to paste my complete code here.... But again, problem is the same. Is there any way I can provide the complete code  ?

Comment: You can add it to your original question, but doesn't my answer give you enough of a framework to figure it out?

Comment: Well, let me thank u for giving your time and brains....I understood what you suggested, and it works fine for a section of code. But when I am using it with the complete code, its failing. I am providing the complete code. I really need to learn where I am going wrong.

Comment: I believe I have provided you with an ample framework to incorporate into your code.  It is not up to us to rewrite all your code for you.

Comment: Code modified per your request.